# How to upload an existing QGIS project to QField organization

Tags: qfield, qfieldsync, qfield-cloud

I am trying to upload an existing QGIS project onto QField for an organization to use. It is easy to do this under my personal account, but I can find zero information about how to do this for an organization. I can only "create a new project" for the organization, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is 'the' answer, but for me with a personal and an organisational account, this is how it works:

1. From the QGIS document using the QField toolbar > Synchronise button, 'create new project' (my data is in postgis with edits going back into there so this is the option to use). This will create the raw cloud project on my personal account.
2. Once the cloud project been created, sync it so the project file and associated data are uploaded.
3. From the Qfield Cloud management webpage, edit the project's settings and transfer ownership to your organisation.